# ArgumentOutOfRangeException was Unhandled , Index was out of range

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I want to ask if anyone knows this why this error occurs? So there are 2 forms. The first calculation form there is no error and this is the second calculation form which produces the error, after searching here and there masi not yet enlightenment, maybe someone can help?

[THIS SCREENSHOT OF ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7hcM.png)

this full source code

```
Public Class FrmHitung2
    Private Sub FrmHitung2_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim dt As DataTable = openDT("SELECT * FROM tb_rel_alternatif2 WHERE kode_crips NOT IN (SELECT kode_crips FROM tb_crips2)")
        If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            msgError("Anda belum mengatur nilai untuk setiap alternatif, silahkan atur di menu Nilai Bobot")
            BtnCetak.Enabled = False
        Else
            Dgv1.AllowUserToAddRows = False
            Dgv1.AllowUserToDeleteRows = False
            Dgv1.ReadOnly = True
            Dgv1.AutoGenerateColumns = False
            awal()
        End If
    End Sub
    Sub awal()
        Dgv1.Columns.Clear()
        Dgv1.Rows.Clear()

        Dgv1.Columns.Add("nim", "Kode")
        Dgv1.Columns("nim").ReadOnly = True
        Dgv1.Columns.Add("nama_mahasiswa", "Nama")
        Dgv1.Columns("nama_mahasiswa").ReadOnly = True

            dr = openDR("SELECT * FROM tb_alternatif2 ORDER BY nim")
            While dr.Read()
                Dgv1.Rows.Add(dr(0), dr(1))
            End While

            dr = openDR("SELECT kode_kriteria, atribut FROM tb_kriteria2 ORDER BY kode_kriteria")
            While dr.Read()
                Dgv1.Columns.Add(dr(0), dr(0))
                Dgv1.Columns(dr(0).ToString()).ToolTipText = dr(1).ToString()
            End While

            For a = 0 To Dgv1.Rows.Count - 1
                dr = openDR("SELECT c.nama_crips FROM tb_rel_alternatif2 r " &
                            " LEFT JOIN tb_crips2 c ON c.kode_crips = r.kode_crips " &
                            " WHERE nim='" & Dgv1.Rows(a).Cells(0).Value & "' ORDER BY r.kode_kriteria")
                Dim b As Integer = 2
                While dr.Read
                    Dgv1.Rows(a).Cells(b).Value = dr(0)
                    b = b + 1
                End While
            Next
            Dgv1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells
            BtnCetak.Enabled = False
    End Sub
    Function get_col_max(ByVal dgv As DataGridView, ByVal col_name As String) As Double
        Dim max As Double = 0
        If dgv.Rows.Count > 0 Then max = Val(dgv.Rows(0).Cells(col_name).Value)
        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgv.Rows
            If Val(row.Cells(col_name).Value) > max Then
                max = Val(row.Cells(col_name).Value)
            End If
        Next
        get_col_max = max
    End Function

    Function get_col_min(ByVal dgv As DataGridView, ByVal col_name As String) As Double
        Dim min As Double = 0
        If dgv.Rows.Count > 0 Then min = Val(dgv.Rows(0).Cells(col_name).Value)
        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In dgv.Rows
            If Val(row.Cells(col_name).Value) < min Then
                min = Val(row.Cells(col_name).Value)
            End If
        Next
        get_col_min = min
    End Function
    Private Sub BtnHitung_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnHitung.Click
        Dim a, b As Integer

        awal()

        Dgv1.copyTo(Dgv2)

        For a = 0 To Dgv2.Rows.Count - 1
            dr = openDR("SELECT c.nilai FROM tb_rel_alternatif2 r " &
                        " LEFT JOIN tb_crips2 c ON c.kode_crips = r.kode_crips " &
                        " WHERE nim='" & Dgv2.Rows(a).Cells(0).Value & "' ORDER BY r.kode_kriteria")
            b = 2
            While dr.Read
                Dgv2.Rows(a).Cells(b).Value = dr(0)
                b = b + 1
            End While
        Next
        Dgv2.copyTo(Dgv3)
        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In Dgv2.Rows
            For b = 2 To Dgv2.Columns.Count - 1
                Dim v = row.Cells(b).Value
                If Dgv2.Columns(b).ToolTipText = "benefit" Then
                    Dgv3.Rows(row.Index).Cells(b).Value = v / get_col_max(Dgv2, Dgv2.Columns(b).Name)
                Else
                    Dgv3.Rows(row.Index).Cells(b).Value = get_col_min(Dgv2, Dgv2.Columns(b).Name) / v
                End If
            Next
        Next

        dr = openDR("SELECT kode_kriteria, bobot FROM tb_kriteria2 ORDER BY kode_kriteria")
        While dr.Read()
            Dgv3.Columns(dr(0).ToString()).ToolTipText = dr(1).ToString()
        End While

        Dgv3.copyTo(Dgv4)
        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In Dgv3.Rows
            For b = 2 To Dgv3.Columns.Count - 1
                Dim v = row.Cells(b).Value
                Dgv4.Rows(row.Index).Cells(b).Value = v * Val(Dgv3.Columns(b).ToolTipText)
            Next
        Next
        Dgv4.Columns.Add("total", "Total")
        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In Dgv4.Rows
            For b = 2 To Dgv2.Columns.Count - 1
                row.Cells("total").Value = row.Cells("total").Value + row.Cells(b).Value
            Next
        Next

        Dgv4.copyTo(Dgv5)
        Dgv5.Sort(Dgv5.Columns("total"), System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Descending)
        For Each row As DataGridViewRow In Dgv5.Rows
            execute("UPDATE tb_alternatif2 SET total=@0, rank=@1 WHERE nim=@2", row.Cells("total").Value, row.Index + 1, row.Cells("nim").Value)
        Next

        TabControl1.SelectedTab = TabRangking
        BtnCetak.Enabled = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnCetak_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnCetak.Click
        LapRangking.ShowAsChild(Me.MdiParent)
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnKeluar_Click_1(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnKeluar.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Please reformat your question, some of your code is not in the right format. Also, please write your code in Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example...

Answer (score 0):

That error occurs when you try to access an array or other collection with an index that doesn't exist. Note that indexing starts at 0 all the way to `Count - 1`.

From you screenshot I can see the error occurs at this line `Dgv1.Rows(a).Cells(b).Value = dr(0)`. **a** is defined in a For loop this way, `For a = 0 To Dgv1.Rows.Count - 1` so it is unlikely that is the culprit.

You may want to check the value of **b** which you have started with a value of 2. If you're trying to access the second item in the collection, you will have to change that line to read...

```
Dim b As Integer = 1 ' If you wanted to start from the 2nd cell.
    While dr.Read
    Dgv1.Rows(a).Cells(b).Value = dr(0)
    b = b + 1
End While
```

**b** is likely growing past the number of cells you have and causing that problem.

**Note:** *I have changed the definition of b to start at 1*

**Update 2**

After looking at your code again, I'm seeing something that I seem to have missed when looking at line that caused the error. You are defining b as, `Dim b As Integer = 2 ' I recommended changing that to 1` and using it to access the columns in your dataset/reader. But when I look at your queries, something else reveals itself. The 1st one in the `awal()` method is

```
SELECT * FROM tb_alternatif2 ORDER BY nim
```

which returns an ordered set with an unknown (to me anyway) number of rows and columns. You are then looping through adding the 1st and 2nd columns of the data reader to rows of what I assume is a data grid view. After that, you make a call to another query

```
SELECT kode_kriteria, atribut FROM tb_kriteria2 ORDER BY kode_kriteria
```

which returns an ordered set with 2 columns that you add as columns to the data grid view. Next you have the query

```
SELECT c.nama_crips FROM tb_rel_alternatif2 r --... truncated
```

which returns one column which is when you are defining **b**. Somewhere between the number of columns you are creating and then addressing them with b, you are probably hitting an off by one error. Or more than off by one. Assuming the 2nd query creates for you 10 columns and the third query returns 15 rows, you will quickly run out of columns to address using `.Cells(b).Value` in your code.

It is unclear to me what you are trying to do with this, but I would recommend trying to define your query again and binding once to the data grid. **As an aside:** I would also recommend using parameters for constructing your queries because the way you have done isn't too secure... SQL injection and all that.

Comment: So what should i do for it ?

Comment: Was you intention to start with the second cell? If so, you will notice I changed the code in my answer to start with `Dim b As Integer = 1`.

Answer (score 0):

Why are your using `dr.Read()` at one place and `dr.Read` in another. Underlined in RED. Maybe the DataReader is not populated yet!, It should be `dr.Read()`

[image: Here]

Comment: So what should i do for it?

Comment: Obvious, `while dr.Read()` instead of `while dr.Read`

Comment: @SurajS VB is not fussy about having the parentheses after a method call as long as not arguments are being passed to it.

Comment: i have five columns @Suraj S

Comment: Hi @JohanPristiawan, I've just seen this comment after posting an edit to my answer. I raised some concerns that may point you in the right direction, or that you may find useful. I still can't discern everything in your code so would need some more information either by way of editing the question or more comments on your question.